# closed-form analytical expression for DFT coefficients

Tags: dft

I want to calculate the closed-form analytical expression for DFT coefficients of the following problem

> $$x[n]=\left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>   1  & \mbox{if } 0\leq n \leq M-1 \\
>   0 & \mbox{if }M \leq n \leq L-1
>  \end{array}
> \right.$$
>   Write out the closed-form analityical expression for its DFT coefficients $X[k]$.

I always get the wrong solution... My attempted solution is: $$\frac{1 - e^{-j\pi k \frac{M}{L}} }{ 1 - e^{-j\pi k \frac{1}{L}} }$$

What is the correct solution and why?

Answer (score 3):

The DFT of a vector of size L is L samples of the Fourier transform of the signal:

$$
X[k] = X(e^{j\theta})|_{\theta = 2\pi k/L}
$$

So now we need to calculate the FT of $x[n]$:

$$
X(e^{j\theta}) = \sum_{n=0}^{n=M-1} e^{-j n \theta}
$$

This is a geometric series which results in:

$$
X(e^{j\theta}) = \frac{1 - e^{-jM\theta}}{1 - e^{-j\theta}}
$$

Evaluate on the DFT samples to give:

$$
X[k] = \frac{1 - e^{-j M 2 \pi k/L}}{1 - e^{-j 2 \pi k / L}}
$$

You can extract half phase from top and bottom to give:

$$
X[k] = e^{-j(M-1)\pi k/L} \frac{\sin(M \pi k/L)}{\sin(\pi k/L)}
$$

Comment: E^(-j*(M-1)*pi*k/L)*sin(M*pi*k/L)/sin(pi*k/L)

Answer (score 0):

As per my analysis, the answer should be
[image]

I used the DFT formula for a discrete sequence
[image]

I integrated the above in two parts.

First from n=0 to M-1

and

Second from n=M to L-1

As per the given conditions the x<sub>n</sub> will be zero for the second part

This reduces to a geometric series

[image]

where

$$a=1$$

and

$$r=e^{-j*2*pi*k/L}$$

and
$$n=M-1$$

Comment: welcome to the DSP SE, Sau001.  in the future, it would be better to do all of your equations with $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson  Absolutely! Still learning LatEx.